# compile with clang from the command line: compatibility issues mac os X

Tags: c++, macos, c++14, clang++

I am compiling a c++14 project on MacOsX10.10 using cmake, clang++, boost and openCV (static linkage - compilation flags: -Wall -std=c++14 -O3). How can I make sure the program runs out-of-the-box in older MacOsX versions? (and in other mac computers as well?) I've tested the binary on an older macbook running os X 10.7 and it failed. With xcode it's possible to build a program against some particular SDK, can I do something similar from the command line?

P.S. This is a more general question, but the source code for this particular project can be found here: https://github.com/MarinosK/oiko-nomic-threads

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure that all dependencies are linked statically into your executable. So this not only includes the .a (static libraries or object archives) but also the C++ (and possibly C) standard libraries.

For example:

```
clang --std=c++14 -stdlib=libstdc++ main.cpp -o main thirdparty.a -static -lstdc++
```

Comment: I thought that apple discourages static linking against stdc++. according to this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1118/_index.html) : "Apple does not support statically linked binaries on Mac OS X. A statically linked binary assumes binary compatibility at the kernel system call interface, and we do not make any guarantees on that front. Rather, we strive to ensure binary compatibility in each dynamically linked system library and framework." I also read somewhere that apple is about to drop support for libstdc++ in favour of libc++. I'll try this tho, thx.